# Is there a way to gather data of Optical Module Status and the CPU Utilization through SNMP protocol?

Tags: networking

When using the snmpwalk command to query a **Cisco SF302-08PP** switch with the -c public community string, am not able to find data related to Optical Module Status and CPU Utilization. I am trying to collect the data of a switch through snmp protocol using the following command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public IP_ADDRESS_CONNECTED_SWITCH
```

Is there a recommended solution or alternative approach to successfully retrieve data on Optical Module Status and CPU Utilization through SNMP for this particular switch model?

Comment: Cisco likes to be a leader in switch capability.  That translates to them usually having their own (and generally very annoying) way of doing things.